# Debugging error 500 issues in Python EVE

Tags: python, eve

What is the best way to debug error 500 issues in Python EVE on the resources?
I'm having a problem with my PATCH method in one of my item end points. Is there an options to get more verbose error or catching the exceptions with the proper info before we get the error 500.

My database is MongoDB and I'm using Cerberus styled schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you switch debug mode on you will get exception message within the body of the response. Just set `DEBUG = True` in your settings, or run the application like this:

```
from eve import Eve

app = Eve()
app.run(debug=True)
```

Furthermore, if you really want to dig in, you could clone the repository and install from it (`pip install -e <path to the repo>`. Then you can set your own breakpoints directly in the source code.